# Numeric value of a user entered string

Tags: string, sum

I need to write a code that returns the sum of the numeric value  of a user entered string. Example if the user enters aa the sum will be 2, bb the sum will be 4. This is what I have. any help would be much appreciated. I realise the hash map method might not be the most efficient however I would like to do it this way. My problem is getting the sum of the result

enter code here

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Map<Character, Integer> map;

    System.out.println("Plaese enter a sentence:");

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String str = read.nextLine();

    map = new HashMap<>();  
    // or map = new HashMap<Character, Integer> if you are using something before Java 7.
    map.put('a', 1);
    map.put('b', 2);
    map.put('c', 3);
    map.put('d', 4);
    map.put('e', 5);
    map.put('f', 6);
    map.put('g', 7);
    map.put('h', 8);
    map.put('i', 9);
    map.put('j', 10);
    map.put('k', 11);
    map.put('l', 12);
    map.put('m', 13);
    map.put('n', 14);
    map.put('o', 15);
    map.put('p', 16);
    map.put('q', 17);
    map.put('r', 18);
    map.put('s', 19);
    map.put('t', 20);
    map.put('u', 21);
    map.put('v', 22);
    map.put('w', 23);
    map.put('x', 24);
    map.put('y', 25);
    map.put('z', 26);



    for(final char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        final Integer val;

        val = map.get(c);

        if(val == null)
        {  
            // some sort of error
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(val + " ");

        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    String numbers = val.nextLine();  //String would be 55
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : numbers.toCharArray()) {
        sum += c - '0';
    }
    System.out.println(sum); //the answer is 10
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
var str = "aa";
var strArray = str.split('');
var letterValArray = strArray.map(char => char.charCodeAt(0) - 96);
var sum = 0;
letterValArray.forEach(num => sum += num)
```

Comment: Sorry! I assumed you were working in javascript, maybe something similar can still work for you

Answer (score 0):

You could do your summing using the HashMap.  You could in the for loop do sum+=map.get(c).  (Declare sum and initialize it with 0 before the loop)

```
sum=0
for(final char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        final Integer val;

        val = map.get(c);

        if(val == null)
        {  
            // some sort of error
        }
        else
        {
             sum+=map.get(c);
             System.out.print(val + " ");

        }
    }
```